# Blender 2.92 - No visibility tab in Cycles. Need to make a shadow catcher but the option is not there

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to make a shadow catcher object in blender, but in the Material properties tab of the Properties panel, there isn't any dropdown for Visibility like there should be. This goes for all objects for some reason. Any ideas on how to make an object into a shadow catcher in Cycles 2.92 without that dropdown? Or is there some way for me to enable that dropdown?

Comment: Shadow catcher is under Object Properties > Visibility

Comment: The visibility dropdown dowsn't appear under the object properties tab for me.  I can't figure out why.  I'm definitely in Cycles and I definitely have an object selected.  I've tried with numerous documents and objects.  Tried reinstalling the program too.

Answer (score 1):

Is under object properties > Visibility

[image]

Comment: That visibility tab isn't there for me.  That's the problem.  It simply doesn't appear.
Yes the object is selected, yes I'm in the Object Properties tab you're in, and yes I'm in Cycles.  The visibility dropdown simply isn't there.